# Dynamic listview onclick

Tags: android, listview, dynamic

hey I have successfully viewed my data from parse.com in listview but new I want to filter the data depends on their category as you can see in figure 1 that there are different categories when the user clicks on a button a listview must be appeared under the clicked button.

can anyone help to achieve it ? would be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just sort your data by category and use [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) instead of `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

you can sort your List with `Collections.sort(yourList)` or if you use Sqlite you can Select from database all what you need.

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(newOnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick (AdapterView < ? > adapter, View view,int position, long arg){
          /// yours operations.......
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: the categories are not listview , actually they are buttons as you seen in figure 1 .